# plotting pie chart using reactJs with chartjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am trying to plot pie chart using react and chartjs.

i am calling an API like this:-

```
const border ={
    border:'1px solid blue',
    borderRadius: '25px',
    padding:'15px',
    marginTop:'20px'
}

class ScreenView extends Component {



constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        newUsers:'',
        allUsers:'',
        totalApplication:'',
        chartData:{},
            newuserstoday:'',
            candidatesOnliveAdvt:'',
            totalsignuptilltoday:'',
            genderDetails:{
                male:'',
                female:'',
                other:''
            }
        }

    }


componentDidMount(){

    const newChartData = {...this.state.chartData}

    let url4 ="http://localhost:7080/getGenderAgainstAdvt";

    getAllData(url4).then(
       response => this.setState({genderDetails:response.data},()=>{
        console.log("male gender count: "+this.state.genderDetails.male);
        console.log("female gender count: "+this.state.genderDetails.female);
        console.log("other gender count: "+this.state.genderDetails.others);
       })

    );

}
componentWillMount(){

    this.getChartData();
}

getChartData(){
    // Ajax calls here

    let maleCount = this.state.genderDetails.male;
    let femaleCount = this.state.genderDetails.female;
    let otherCount = this.state.genderDetails.other;

    console.log("male count is " +maleCount);


    this.setState({
      chartData:{
        labels: ['Male', 'Female', 'Other'],
        datasets:[
          {
            label:'Population',
            data:[
            maleCount,femaleCount,otherCount
            ],
            backgroundColor:[
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.6)'
            ],
            borderWidth:1,
            hoverBorderWidth:3,
            hoverBorderColor:'green'
          }
        ]
      }
    });
  }


render(){
    return(
    <div>
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row" style={border}>
                <div className="col-sm-8">
                    <Chart chartData={this.state.chartData}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    );
}
}

export default ScreenView;
```

and my other component Chart looks like this:-

```
class Chart extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          chartData:props.chartData
        }
        //console.log("chart data is here...."+ props.chartData.datasets[0].data[0].male);
      }

      static defaultProps = {
        displayTitle:true,
        displayLegend: true,
        legendPosition:'right',
        location:'16530-16536/2074-75'
      }

      render(){
        return (
          <div className="chart">
            <Pie
              data={this.state.chartData}
              options={{
                title:{
                  display:this.props.displayTitle,
                  text:'Pie Chart for Advertisement Code '+this.props.location,
                  fontSize:25
                },
                legend:{
                  display:this.props.displayLegend,
                  position:this.props.legendPosition
                }
              }}
            />
          </div>
        )
      }
}
```

my API returns very simple JSON which looks like this:-

```
{
    "male": 74433,
    "female": 51442,
    "others": 183
}
```

i need to fetch this API data and plot the pie chart according to it. my problem here is i cannot send the API returned data to chart dataset.

if i send some manual data to the chart i.e

```
datasets:[
          {
            label:'Population',
            data:[
           12345,54758,2154
            ],
}]
```

then it successfully plots data. but when now i have to use API fetched data instead of manually inserted data. how can i do it ?

**update:-**

my chart component was not receiving data. so i changed `this.state.chartData` to `this.props.chartData` and it half working. half working in a sense that i am now able to plot the chart but it only plots two given value out of three.

please see photos.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the props data directly to render the chart like this:

```
<Pie
    data={this.props.chartData}
    ...
    ...
```

Every time your parent `ScreenView` fetch new data, that data will be sent down to the child `Chart` component and it will re-render it

Comment: Could you please try with a bigger other value, comparing it to the others it's percentage would be less than one. Chartjs may not draw if it's below 1%

Comment: ohh!! this might be the reason but this is real time data so adding high value manually won't make sense.